# Remove leading zeroes in pandas column but only for numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe looks as follows:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC8392akl |
| 2 | 001523 |
| 3 | 000ABC58 |

Now I want to remove the leading zeroes, if the string is only numerical. Any suggestions?
So outcome should be:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC8392akl |
| 2 | 1523 |
| 3 | 000ABC58 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for this:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r'^0+(?!.*\D)', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
   col1        col2
0     1  ABC8392akl
1     2        1523
2     3    000ABC58
```

regex:

```
^0+       # match leading zeros
(?!.*\D)  # only if not followed at some point by a non digit character
```

##### variant

suggested by @timgeb

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r'^0+(\d*)$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

regex:

```
^0+       # match leading zeros
(\d*)     # capture other digits (if any)
$         # match end of string
```

replace with captured digits (`\1`)

Comment: I'd use `df['col2'].str.replace(r'^0+([\d]*)$', r'\1')`, easier to read imo.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
where = (df['col2'].str.isdigit(), 'col2')
df.loc[where] = df.loc[where].str.lstrip('0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem with this, or you want to keep the numbers as string?

```
df['col2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col2'] ,errors='ignore')
```